# Is it possible to use TtsSpan with compose to change the way texts are pronounced?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, talkback

I'm currently working on a compose screen that has a list of telephone numbers. I'm wanting the screen reader to read the phone number individually. I know there's a way to do that for the old UI tool kit. I haven't seen any attempts for doing it in compose. Is there a way to do this using TtsSpan or is there a completely different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Compose supports TtsSapn](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder#addTtsAnnotationandroidx.compose.ui.text.TtsAnnotation,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int), but it supports only `VerbatimTtsAnnotation`.